# Loading JSON file into script variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON file with city names and their ids. I want to load only the city names into a script variable so I can use that variable as a source in autocomplete for jQuery.

Data Example:

```
{
    "cities": [
        {
            "id": 1440,
            "name": "Bundi"
        },
        {
            "id": 850,
            "name": "Beed"
        },
        {
            "id": 1409,
            "name": "Kankroli"
        },
        {
            "id": 1913,
            "name": "Muniyal Herbals And Ayurvedic Remedies Limited"
        },
        {
            "id": 2418,
            "name": "Kunnicode"
        }]
}
```

Comment: `names = cities.map(function(v){ return v.name })`

Comment: Thank u that line helped at the end lot...

Answer (score 1):

```
var someVar = JSON.parse(someStringContainingYourJSON) 


someVar.cities[0].id.. etc
someVar.cities[1].id
```

or you can use

```
$.getJSON('/url',function(someVar){
   someVar.cities[0].id.. etc
    someVar.cities[1].id

})
```

Comment: i have almost 20k line of names.so i want them to be in json file and load them from file.

Comment: then you should use jquery ajax to load it.

Comment: if you have a string with the json, use JSON.parse

Comment: can u please give me a sample how to do that.Suppose if file name is cities.json.wat would be the code in jquery ajax.

Comment: try the above using getJSON

Comment: in url should i give the full path of the file or just name if it is in the same folder.

Comment: You don't need a 'json file' per se. You've got a very large JSON object, but there's nothing that requires it to be in a file with a fancy extension. Simply save your cities object into a text file with a '.js' extension, and either include it in your HTML as a separate script reference ABOVE the jQuery code you want to write, or reference it from within your jQuery file using something like `var someVar = require("./mylistofcities.js")`.